# Using perspective.lua for moving camera and object parralaxRatio

Tags: lua, coronasdk, perspectivecamera

I develop my project using Corona SDK and creating successfully a "virtual moving camera".

The problem I have is about the parameter : ParallaxRatio() It seems it doesn't work, because my camera move the object in the same "speed". I would like the mountain & mountain2 move faster than the bkg_1.

Here is my code:

```
local perspective = require("perspective")
local camera = perspective.createView()

camera:add(hero,1,true)
camera:add(grass,2,false)
camera:add(mountain,3,false)
camera:add(mountain2,3,false)
camera:layer(3).parallaxRatio=0.5
camera:add(bkg_1,4,false)
camera:layer(4).parallaxRatio=0.2
camera:add(bg,5,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a separate function to move the mountains along the x axis.

```
local function moveMountain(event)
    mountain.x = mountain.x - 1.5
    if mountain.x <removePoint then                    
        mountain.x = player.x +950
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",mountain)

Cloud_1.enterFrame = moveMountain
```